# python SimpleHTTPServer suspended, how to stop?

Tags: python, macos, networking, port

I accidentally hit ctrl z instead of ctrl c to stop python SimpleHTTPServer and it came up saying

```
[1]  + 35296 suspended  python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

now I cannot restart it on the same port as port 8000 is in use

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py",      line 162, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 220, in <module>
test()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SimpleHTTPServer.py", line 216, in test
BaseHTTPServer.test(HandlerClass, ServerClass)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 595, in test
httpd = ServerClass(server_address, HandlerClass)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 419, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 430, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 224, in meth
return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 48] Address already in use
```

How can I stop this process so that I can use port 8000 again?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process is suspended in the background, you'll have to kill it for it to release the port.

If you're in the same terminal, running `fg` will bring it to the front and reactivate it, letting you interrupt it normally with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

If you're not, you can use that number that got printed (the process ID, or PID) to kill it, but you'll first have to reactivate it, so that it can react:

```
kill -CONT 35296
kill 35296
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a nicely detailed answer

Answer (score 2):

Kill the process.

```
kill 35296
```

or:

```
kill %1
```

Answer (score 1):

use `fg` to bring it to the foreground, and then you can kiil it using ctrl+c